# How to pass a MySQL JSON object from connection.query() to res.render()

Tags: javascript, node.js

As the title suggests, I am having trouble accessing an object from a MySQL response outside of the `connection.query()` function.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var testimonials;

    // Running database queries
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM testimonials', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            testimonials = rows;
            console.log(testimonials); // THIS WORKS
        }
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error performing database query.');
        }
    });


  res.render('index', {
      title: 'Title',
      description: 'Description in here.',
      testimonials: testimonials // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your `res.render` inside the callback function, e.g:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {    
    var testimonials;

    // Running database queries
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM testimonials', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            testimonials = rows;

            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Title',
                description: 'Description in here.',
                testimonials: testimonials // this will work!!!
            });
        }
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error performing database query.');
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: you get `undefined` when you use `testimonials` outside the callback function because the method `connection.query` is asynchronous and it will run **after** your `res.render` method.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @jacobwarduk if my answer was useful for you, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the `V` right below the upvote/downvote arrows. Thanks! :)